# How to get the polymer-cli (1.0.0) to use the latest version of polymer (2.0.0)

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

I just updated the polymer cli, on my linux pc to the freshly released version 1.0.0 (as confirmed by the polymer --version command).
However when I use the cli to set up a new polymer-2-application project, the bower.json file is still pointing to the 2.0.0-rc.3 version of polymer and other pre 2.0 release candidate dependencies.

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0-rc.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-component-tester": "^6.0.0-prerelease.5",
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^1.0.0-rc.7"
  }
}
```

How can I get polymer-cli to use the newly released stable 2.0.0 version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you are actually looking for the `polymer-cli` update. The `polymer-cli` is ran from a terminal and has commands for building, linting, serving, etc. The current version of the CLI is 1.0.0 as of today.

To update the CLI use, `npm i -g polymer-cli`

I believe what you are really asking about is the Polymer library which was tagged the other day as stable 2.0.0. you can update the line in your `bower.json` to point to `^2.0.0` instead of `^2.0.0-rc.3`. Take a look at the Polymer Starter Kit for other dependency updates you should probably make. https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/2.0-preview/bower.json

If you don't feel like taking a look...

```
{
  "name": "temp",
  "main": "index.html",
  "dependencies": {
    "polymer": "Polymer/polymer#^2.0.0",
    "webcomponentsjs": "webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "web-component-tester": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade

Comment: I agree that changing the references toward the polymer and webcomponentsjs version within bower.json file would solve my issue. But since the polymer-cli 1.0.0 version was released shortly after the Polymer 2.0.0 stable release, I would expect that a `polymer init` would point to the stable Polymer release and not an older release candidate. I therefore was wondering if there is a setting somewhere installed with a previous version that isn't overwritten with the updated polymer-cli, that causes the setup of new projects to still use an older bower.json file as a base.

Comment: Ah, yeah, the templates were out of date. Seems they were overlooked. There was an issue logged for it. https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/issues/750. I submitted a PR to update the templates to the latest. https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli/pull/752. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanxs, I missed the issue posted in github. That answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to run `npm install -g polymer-cli@next` instead of the regular polymer-cli.

More information can be found here: https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/upgrade

Comment: If I run `npm install -g polymer-cli@next` I get version 0.18.1, not the 1.0.0 version or later as I would expect. I also see no reference of @next part anymore in the upgrade guide (the link you provided). Finally if I use the 0.18.1 cli version I got I still get the reference toward the 2.0.0.-rc.3 version not the final stable 2.0.0 version I would expect.